# Nginx no inicia: directiva desconocida "pagespeed"

Tags: nginx, certbot

Buenas,

Llevo más de un año usando Nginx con PageSpeed para incrementar la carga, compresión y caché de mis paginas web. Soy dueño de un acortador de URLS con millones de visitas mensuales. Instalé el **certbot** para añadir HTTPS al sitio web con Let's Encrypt y desde aquel momento reinicié Nginx con `service nginx restart` y comenzé a experimentar problemas.

A continuación dejo el error completo (fuente: `systemctl status nginx.service`) para depurificar el error que ocurre al iniciar Nginx.

```
systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-10-11 18:12:55 EDT; 4s ago
  Process: 9090 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 14066 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Oct 11 18:12:55 vps118687 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Oct 11 18:12:55 vps118687 nginx[9090]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "pagespeed" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/pagepseed.conf:2
Oct 11 18:12:55 vps118687 nginx[9090]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Oct 11 18:12:55 vps118687 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 11 18:12:55 vps118687 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Oct 11 18:12:55 vps118687 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 11 18:12:55 vps118687 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**ACTUALIZACION**

**Parece que al instalar el certbot nginx se volvió a instalar, como puedo solucionar esto y dejar la versión antigua?
`whereis nginx` retorna `/usr/sbin/nginx /etc/nginx /usr/local/sbin/nginx /usr/local/nginx /usr/share/nginx`**

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Quizá falte el modulo que interpreta la directiva "pagespeed", prueba instalarlo de nuevo como dice la documentacion (supongo que es esta ->) https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source

Comment: Tienes que realizar la instalación de nginx con la compatibilidad para pagespeed de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

debes instalar y cargar el módulo correspondiente para que la directiva pagespeed esté disponible en Nginx:

```
bash <(curl -f -L -sS https://ngxpagespeed.com/install) --nginx-version latest
```

Para más información ve a: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/?hl=es-419